# Some logged info(using console.log in angular) keeps disappearing from console after reloading webpage

Tags: html, angular

I'm making a website using spring for my backend and angular and html as frontend.

I have two tables(services/offers) in my MySQL database(the offers table has a serviceName foreign key which is at the same time the service table primary key).

I have an angular component that calls the two database tables and puts them into two different arrays.

I was trying to make a new array in angular that has the number of occurrences of each serviceName in the offers array but when i tried to log(console.log) the new list sometimes it's empty and sometimes doesn't even appear.

Here's the angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-offrea',
    templateUrl: './offrea.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./offrea.component.scss']
})
export class OffreaComponent implements OnInit {

    loginuser: any = {};
    offres: any[] = [];
    services: any[] = [];
    countList: any[] = [];
    count: number;
    constructor(private service: UserService) {
        this.service.getAllOffer().subscribe(o => {
            this.offres = o;
        });
        this.service.getServices().subscribe(ser => {
            this.services = ser;
        });
        this.f(this.offres, this.services);
        console.log(this.countList);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    f(a1, a2) {
        for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            this.count = 0;
            for (let z = 0; z < a2.length; z++) {
                if (a1[i].services.serviceName === a2[z].serviceName) {
                    this.count++;
                    this.countList.push(this.count);
                }
            }
            this.count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is you are calling two asynchronous functions (the `subscribes` which are making HTTP requests) in a synchronous manner. Meaning, by the time you get to your `this.f(...)` and `console.log` calls, your http calls *may* or *may not* have completed yet.

The solution is to combine your subscribes into one function and call `this.f(...)` and `console.log` inside the subscribe callback. You can use either the RxJS [combineLastest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) or [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). I used the `forkJoin` in my answer because http observables complete.

Here is a stackblitz with the working code (the user.service.ts was mocked out). https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvfsft

In **offera.component.ts**

```js
// beginning of file...

  /* I recommend moving your logic to ngOnInit */
  ngOnInit() {
    // You need to combine your two calls
    //  you can use combineLatest or forkJoin
    forkJoin(
      this.service.getAllOffer(),
      this.service.getServices(),
    ).subscribe(([offres, services]) => {
      this.offres = offres;
      this.services = services;
      this.f(this.offres, this.services);
      console.log(this.countList);
    });
  }

// rest of file...
```

The main difference between `forkJoin` and `combineLatest` is:

- `forkJoin` requires all observables to complete before passing values to the subscriber. This is considered a "cold" observables because it will only emit once.
- `combineLatest` requires all observables to *emit at least once* before it passes any values to subscriber. It has some other great behavior, but bottom line is this usually returns a hot observable. You will want to read the docs on this if you want to know more.

Hope this works for you. Cheers!